# Customizing Addthis Plugin - passing url using classic asp

Tags: facebook, twitter, asp-classic, facebook-opengraph, addthis

I am having lots of problems while coming up with a solution. 
I have a website that share text or image greetings( text greeting only at this time) on facebook or twitter etc. I planed to use Addthis. 
So I created a function like this

```
<%
 Function DisplayShareDiv(surl, sT, sSummary)
%>
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" 
     addthis:url="<%=surl%>" 
     addthis:title="<%=sT %>" 
     id="addthis_container" 
     addthis:Description="<%=sSummary%>">

<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>



</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": true };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=###################3"></script>
 <!-- AddThis Button END -->
<%
end function 
%>
```

Now problem is that title appears when click on facebook or twitter but url doesn't. I also want to add the description to it. I have og tags too but they need to be dynamic too and i am having problems with fb not picking up that info either. Even though i have run it through debugger. I am at it for 2 days and it is now all a mish mash. I would really appreciate if someone can please help me!!

Comment: can you see the url on your page when you view source? Do you have it live somewhere, so we can have a look?

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Yes the link is [link](http://www.expertsamples.com/Detail.asp?SC=2) `http://www.expertsamples.com/Detail.asp?SC=2` and you can also look at the source to see the og tags and the addthis buttons. just search addthis in the source

Comment: I just posted it on my facebook and it worked ok

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Pic deleted.  Do you know where that text is coming from?  "Sample Greetings, Wishes, Cards, Famous Quotes and much more for New Year, Christmas, Birthday and other various events in your life."

Comment: Think I worked out what was going on... added a new answer, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm getting this. Is that as you require?

[image]

I think facebook was picking up an old version of your page.

The text it picked up were from the OG and description meta tags on your home page.

If you run your page through their debugging tool, that forces it to scrape the latest version of your page. Plus you might get some useful info too.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/